# Accepting another job offer

Tags: job-offer, south-africa

I recently accepted a job offer. I got this job via OfferZen (a South African recruitment app). The job offer document was a very simple document, without any terms and agreements on my side. The document purely states what the company is offering.

I signed the document, let them know that I accept, and let OfferZen know that I accept. Shortly after this, they let me pick a laptop from a website that I will use.

This week I received another offer from another company. The location is much closer, and the pay is much better. Needless to say, I would rather take the new offer.

Could I face repercussions for withdrawing my acceptance?
How do I go about informing them of my choice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accepting job offer, and backing out? How unprofessional is this?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/41613/accepting-job-offer-and-backing-out-how-unprofessional-is-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that the Terms and Conditions of the sign up to OfferZen have something to say about what your situation is. OfferZen will almost certainly be receiving payment for the fact and will enforce their terms and conditions so indirectly affecting you.

The Terms on the OfferZen website say -

***You agree to indemnify and hold OfferZen, its employees, its officers, and its agents harmless from and against any and all claims, damages, obligations, losses, liabilities, costs or debt, and expenses (including but not limited to attorney's fees) arising from your access or use of the OfferZen platform and/or any Service.***

The employer becomes liable for 12.5% of your total annual cost when you accept a job, so this could be a deciding factor.